# Any AspectJ code generation library (like Sun's codemodel for Java code generation)?

Tags: java, code-generation, aspectj

Is there any free library to generate AspectJ code at compile-time (at the annotation processing step for example)? I am looking for something similar to [codemodel](http://namanmehta.blogspot.com/2010/01/use-codemodel-to-generate-java-source.html), but to generate AspectJ code.

Comment: I am pretty sure there isn't, but I love the idea! I thought I was the only one who came up with crazy scenarios like that :-)

Comment: I always wanted that ;D Analyze a class e.g. with reflection, then somhow instrument other classes which call methods of the reflected class. Would be cool if you could do that.

Comment: @Angel you *can* do that with AspectJ

Comment: No with AspectJ I can only specify point cuts that I know in advance. E.g. I get a Class via RMI which I never heared about ... suppose it has a method decodeMessage(Message). If I don't know this method exists or that class exists I can not describe pointcuts for it.

Comment: @Angel if you don't know that method exists, you cannot even call it. Probably that RMI class implements some interface you know about, in that case you can do that with AspectJ. However I love the idea, I hoped it was possible using APT, but unfortunately it seems like it is not yet possible, despite latest ApsectJ compiler version being a Java6 compiler (which should include APT by default).

Comment: @Simone If you mix everything with Maven, it should be possible: maven-processor-plugin at generate-source goal to create AspectJ code, and aspectj-maven-plugin at compile goal to weave it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem like such a library is available.

After doing more reading and analyzing codemodel's source code:

1. Generating pure AspectJ code with codemodel is not possible, since one cannot declare something like:

   public aspect TransactionManager { ... }
2. It is not possible to twist the `JDeclaredClass` item properly to solve 1. You would have to rewrite almost everything from scratch
3. AspectJ5 introduces annotations, meaning we can declare aspects in pure Java:

   @Aspect
      public class TransactionManager { ... }
4. The only really tricky part of @AspectJ seems to be Inter-type Declarations, but a good/viable solution is provided [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-itds.html).

**Conclusion:** It does not seem like a specific library to generate AspectJ code is necessary, one can rely on codemodel only.